# java aes encryption , output has one block more than the input , and without padding

Tags: java, size, aes, output

so i am working on this assignement where i'm suppposed to make my own CBC and CTR algorithms using the predefined aes functions, for now i seem to have a problem, the output's Size is always a Block more than the input (input 64 ,output 80 , and so on ) here's the code i'm using, with hexadecimal to bytes conversion and bytes to hex :

```
public static String encrypt(String PT,String skey) throws Exception, NoSuchPaddingException {
      Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(skey.getBytes("ascii"), "AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] val = hexToBytes(PT);
        byte[] encVal = cipher.doFinal(val);

        return byteToString(encVal);
}
```

the conversion functions are perfectly working, the val size is n * 16 bytes and the encVal size is (n+1) * 16 bytes

Comment: You need to read the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to padding.

```
Cipher.getInstance("AES");
```

uses provider-specific default values for the mode and padding.  For JDK 6 & 7, this would default to `AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding`.

Comment: ah okey so how do i disable default padding ?

Comment: Use `AES/ECB/NoPadding`.  Also read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html